# Can I use a Bootstrap-like framework with a C# based website?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, visual-web-developer

I'm a starter in web developing, weak at **php-js-css** but have **c#** experience.
For a new website project I want to use **c#** but have some problems with the view.
I won't use those *standard-looking* webform controls that I use for desktop apps, I need a better and modern appearance, a "Bootstrap-like view" for webform controls.

#### My goal is:

To be not having to learn js-css in detail for this website project, since it will take extra time for me to learn these. I want to solve this problem with c# compatible and easy to use tools / frameworks if possible.

#### For this purpose:

- can I use a such a recommended framework class with c#,
- or could just a css template do it,
- or is there a 3rd simpler way

It is important for me to choose the right way before I start the project, any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Welcome to SO, 2. This kind of question is not compliant to the goals of SO 3. You can use a CMS and then you need to learn almost nothing! 4. If you want to become a (successful!) web developer, knowing JS and CSS is (almost!) a must!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can.  You need to use javascript or typescript for the UI and then use Asp.Net WebApi to do any of the server-side functionality.  Any of the popular javascript frameworks play very well with WebApi as long as you create the endpoints the correct way.

Here are some tutorials that can help get you started:

- [Hands On Lab: Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)
- [AngularJS CRUD Operations with WebAPI, EF and Bootstrap](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/MY36030914-AngularJS-CRUD-Operations-with-WebAPI,-EF-and-Bootstrap.html)
- [ASP.NET Web API application with Angularjs Forms and Bootstrap](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1080/aspnet-webapi-with-angularjs-bootstrap)
- [Creating your first SPA Application using AngularJS and WebAPI – All CRUD Operations](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2015/12/spa-application-using-angularjs-webapi-all-crud-operations.html)

[Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com) also has a number of video tutorials that are well worth the cost if you can afford it.

Hope that helps.